# c++: detect if a vector is <complex> type within a function

Tags: c++, templates, vector, runtime

I have a template function which prints std::vector types to a file.
is it possible to detect the type of vector in this function and change some prints, say for example, I like to know if its a "complex" type vector and print results in a different format - "x+iy"

code snippet for reference

```
template < typename myVec >
    void VectorPrint2File(const std::vector < myVec > & v,
        const char * str, std::ofstream & fileptr) {
        fileptr << str << std::endl;
        fileptr << "vector size: " << v.size() << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            fileptr << v[i];
            if (i != v.size() - 1)
                fileptr << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you're using c++17, have a look at `if constexpr`.

Comment: This sounds like you may want to look into class inheritance/polymorphism instead of templates.

Comment: @Jacob No. This sounds like the antithesis of "class inheritance/polymorphism"

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap printing code to a function. Add two overloads, first for printing any type, the second specialized for any *std::complex* class instances:

```
template<class T>
void print(std::ofstream& os, const T& var) {
    os << var;
}

template<class T>
void print(std::ofstream& os, const std::complex<T>& var) {
    os << var.real() << " + i" << var.imag();
}
```

and the call in your function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    print(fileptr, v[i]);
    if (i != v.size() - 1)
        fileptr << "\n";
}
```